# How to Dynamically Change Favicon for Dark and Light Mode in Next.js 13 or 14?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a `Next.js 14` application using `App Router` and I'd like to dynamically change the favicon based on the user's color scheme preference (dark or light mode). Currently, I have a black-colored favicon and a white-colored favicon. How can I set up my Next.js 14 app to automatically switch the favicon to the appropriate version when dark mode is activated and revert to the black version in light or default mode?

In previous versions, this could be achieved using the `<Head/>` component. However, in `Next.js` version 14, the new `Metadata` interface has been introduced to describe all the metadata fields. But, now I'm not sure how to achieve the favicon change based on color modes.

###### My Expectation:

- In my `Next.js` version 14 application, I want to dynamically change the `favicon` based on color modes.
- I am expecting that I could programmatically/automatically switch between the black and white `favicon` versions according to the user's color scheme preference (dark or light mode).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since there were no immediate answer when I posted the question, I was searching in the internet and did not find any solution. So, I have read the official [docs about icons](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#icons) and I find the solution myself. Though there were no direct solution in docs but got a hint and it's solved my issue.

I am sharing the code because if anyone encountered into the same issue in future it would help them,

```
// app/layout.tsx
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: 'Website Title',
  description: 'Website description',
  icons: {
    icon: [
      {
        media: '(prefers-color-scheme: light)',
        url: '/images/icon-light.png',
        href: '/images/icon-light.png',
      },
      {
        media: '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',
        url: '/images/icon.png',
        href: '/images/icon-dark.png',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I have to delete `app/icon.png` or any files that by default map the favicon in order to active the `Metadata` interface's `icon`. And, my `favicon or icon images` stored in `public/images/icon-light.png` and `public/images/icon-dark.png`. And, now its working dynamically based on color modes.

### Quick Procedure:

- Delete any `favicon` or `icon` images from `app/` directory.
- Store `favicon or icon images` to `public/images/` directory.
- In `app/Layout.tsx` `metadata.icons.icon` add `url` and `href` path to the stored `images` relative path. ✅

Comment: That's great, it's really helpful. Any idea how you can do this using **next-themes** and **SSR**? I have a switcher, so the current theme may not be the same as the `prefers-color-scheme`. I wonder if there's any way to pass a variable from a client component to a server component or to use a class name.

Comment: @Ayoubk you can not pass any `props` in between client to server components.

Comment: Can you show us what you added to the <head> tag? Trying to do the same thing and no luck with the code above. (Next.js 14.0.4)

Comment: @AmandaKoster When using the [Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata) API, the `<HEAD>` tag should not be used. If I understand your point correctly, try to use the [Metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata) API. Also, in my code, I did not use the `<HEAD>` tag, so I cannot show you.